# Knitr HTML preview fails in RStudio, though render() successfully creates HTML file

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm getting started with `rmarkdown` and `knitr`. In the sample document provided by RStudio, I can successfully use render() to generate an HTML file that views fine in Chrome. However, when I click on the `knit` button, it generates a `.markdown` file and then returns the following error without rendering the preview:

`Error generating HTML preview for ~/path/to/file/report.rmarkdown system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified)`

I think it's getting hung up at the pandoc stage. Is it possible that RStudio is looking for pandoc in the wrong place? Pandoc was already installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Pandoc\pandoc.exe`, but RStudio installed its own instance at `C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe`, so maybe it's looking in the wrong place and/or confusing settings from one with the other?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

And just in case, here's the RMarkdown template I'm starting with:

````
---
title: "Monthly Report"
author: "Kris Shaffer"
date: "February 17, 2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

R version 3.3.2
RStudio 1.0.136
rmarkdown 1.3
knitr 1.15.1
pandoc 1.17.2 (both installations)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was as simple as a file extension. I changed the filename from `report.rmarkdown` to `report.Rmd`. Knit works fine now.